# One line IF in Blazor not outputting correct

Tags: c#, blazor, conditional-operator

I am trying to use the following code.

```
<td>@(piece.Publisher == null ? (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>" : piece.Publisher.Name)</td>
```

It's not producing what I'm intending.  It's literally printing 'No' in the TD.

How can I get it to render the span as HTML?

--UPDATE--
It's odd, I've tried both suggestions and breaking it out in to fill IF statements seems to be the most reliable, but here is an instance where it works fine.

```
<p>Score?: @(piece.ScoreYesNo ? (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-success'>Yes</span>" : (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>")</p>
```

Now if I do the same thing with Publisher, it renders the markup as a string.

```
<p>Publisher: @(piece.Publisher == null ? ((MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>") : piece.Publisher.Name)</p>
```

Notice that the one that works has MarkupString in both the true and false, It's strange.  Anyone understand why it's not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Try wrap in parentheses: `((MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>")`

Comment: With Razor markup stick with `@if(true)....`   The intent of your code is almost unintelligible.

Answer (score 3):

> Anyone understand why it's not working?

The base problem is the [C# rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) that in `x = c ? a : b;` the `a` and `b` expressions must be 'assignment compatible' with `x`.

```
<td>@(piece.Publisher == null 
   ? (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>" 
   : piece.Publisher.Name)</td>
```

You have here the schema `c ? MarkupString : string` and string and MarkupString  are not assignment compatible with each other. It is not obvious that this code would compile at all but it works (ie, no errors) in C#9 and later because the compiler finds a loophole in this overload in RenderTreeBuilder:

```
void AddContent(int sequence, object? textContent)
```

So the `MarkupString` is first cast to `object` and then rendered with `ToString()`, defeating the whole purpose of MarkupString.

Your second sample with   `c ? (MarkupString)"a" : (MarkupString)"b"` works because both expressions now return a MarkupString.

A shorter notation would be `@(new MarkupString(c ? a : b))` but be sure that both `a` and `b` do not expose you to HTML injection. `Publisher.Name` is probably not safe in that regard.